# Is there a way to draw shapes using only CSS & HTML?

Tags: html, css, shapes

I need help with creating shapes in HTML/CSS as separators between one section of a website to another.

this is how it should look like :

[image]

There's an image at the top and content at the bottom and I need to draw those shapes.

help please :)

Comment: Hi, I think it might help for you to read though the following: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: use your browser tools and see what they are using.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have asked this question really isn't the best however this should help you head in the right direction:

https://jsfiddle.net/m6aoLw9f/5/

**HTML**

```
<div class="bluebox"></div>
<div class="blueline"></div>
```

**css**

```
.bluebox {
  position: absolute;

  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;

  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;

  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0.5;

  transform: skew(-5deg, -5deg);
}

.blueline{
   position: absolute;

   top: 12%;
   left: 8%;

   height: 2px;
   width: 250px;

   background-color: blue;
   opacity: 0.5;

   transform: skew(-5deg, -5deg);
}
```